# How do I setup multiple monitors in Burnout Paradise?

Tags: pc, burnout-paradise

I have two monitors and I want to set up Burnout Paradise to use both of them.  When I specified in the game options to use two monitors, instead of spanning across both it put both displays on a single monitor.  What am I missing?

I am running the game on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

What graphics card are you using?

From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/946234-burnout-paradise-the-ultimate-box/48023943) on GameFAQs:

> Burnout™ Paradise The Ultimate Box supports up to three monitors using the 
>   Matrox TripleHead2Go hardware.
>
> NVidia users may also be able to use multiple monitors by configuring 
>   their displays to use 'Horizontal Span' in the NVidia Control Panel."